# What constitutes FDA's First in Class designation for New Molecular Entities?

Tags: pharmacology

What constitutes a First in Class designation for new molecular entities? I've seen this term on FDA documents, as well as in databases (Chembl for example), but I was curious if there are any set criteria for First in Class drugs? The easy definition, in my mind, would be a drug that hits a novel target given its indication. However, if you look at antifungal drugs, you see that drugs with the same target for the same general indication (anti-fungal) treat completely different fungal infections because of their pharmacokinetics.

Are there discrete criteria for the FDA's first-in-class designation for New Molecular Entities?

Comment: [This page](http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/DevelopmentApprovalProcess/DrugInnovation/ucm474696.htm) on the FDA website gives a rather terse definition: "Drugs with a new and unique mechanism for treating a medical condition". I'm not sure how that's applied in practice, though.

Comment: What is FDA? What is the biological problem regarding this molecule?

Comment: @David the FDA is the Food and Drug Administration in the US. Among other things, they are charged with regulating and approving pharmaceuticals.

Comment: @MattDMo — So the question is about public health policy in one particular country, and not about a problem in biology of the type defined in the [Tour].

Answer (score 2):

"First-in-class drugs are ones that use a new and unique mechanism of action for treating a medical condition. These products are often referred to as innovative and cited as offering new treatment options for patients."

Lanthier, M. *et al.* (2013) "An improved approach to measuring drug innovation finds steady rates of first-in-class pharmaceuticals, 1987-2011." *J.Health Aff. (Millwood)* **32**:1433-9;

Pharmaceutical Research and Manufacturers of America. 2015b. Innovative Oncology Medicines Have Led to Impressive Gains in Patient Survivorship. Retrieved August 26, 2015. <www.phrma.org/innovative-oncology-medicines-have-led-to-impressive-gains-in-survivorship>."

From: Lexchin, J. (2016) "How Safe and Innovative Are First-in-Class Drugs Approved by Health Canada: A Cohort Study" *Healthc. Policy* **12**:65-7.